# What you need to buy to communicate with ZigBee and Z-Wave devices?

Tags: raspberry-pi, zigbee, openhab, domoticz, home-assistant

I have raspberry pi 3b+, i want to manage an apartment with **OpenHab**

Support is needed for xiaomi, ikea, philips *(lamps)*, TV and washing machine *(most likely from Samsung or LG)*.

What you need to buy to be able to communicate and control **ZigBee** and *Z-wave (not necessary)* devices?

The network has found such devices: [RaspBee](https://phoscon.de/en/raspbee), [Elelabs ZigBee](https://elelabs.com/products/elelabs_zigbee_shield.html), [CC2531](http://www.ti.com/tool/CC2531EMK), [ConBee II](https://phoscon.de/en/conbee2) - *(as I understand they all work only with ZigBee)*

1. Is there a GPIO Binding for raspberry with ZigBee and Z-Wave support at the same time?
2. And which device of the above is better for working with ZigBee?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a Raspberry PI, you could use https://zigbee2mqtt.io which is based on Node.js.